# Mongotop shows Primary is reading heavily and takes long time to read in sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb

We have a sharded cluster environment with replica sets.
We are hitting with performance issue.
We are using mongos server to connect to data nodes.

When looked at individual data nodes using mongotop found that 
1) Primary is doing reads and showing long time as opposed to secondary.

Please advice if there is any preference setting which needs changing in order to make sure that writes happens on Primary and reads happens on Secondary.
I can see the collection on which reads are taking long time.

Also please advise if there is any setting which checks if data is not written to secondary then wait for it to commit to primary.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your driver to use the readPreference modes "secondary" or "secondaryPreferred" to achieve this. The syntax for specifying the read preference mode is specific to the driver and to the idioms of the programming language used.

However, you should use this with care, since reading from the secondary returns stale data to the application. It might make sense if you have very little write load. A better way to increase performance could be to increase the number of shards.

See also: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/